# Create a combined view list in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I like to have a main page Web part with a link to each one of the shared documents in our portal.

The problem is that they are from different libraries and also I want the SharePoint to keep track of check in and check outs of the files. When I use, Content Editor to add the links, and then click on the list, it download a copy of file and saved changes do not change the original document.

I thought about creating a modified view in that specific library and filter out just one file. Then put that file in the front page. But, the first problem is that the file is 2 or 3 level deep in hierarchy. Also, even if I manage to do that, what should I do about different files in different libraries?

Please Advise